# Text moving to next line without width issues

Tags: html, css, responsive-design

I am completely stumped on an issue I am having. It is the simplest issue, but I just can't locate the issue. I have a line of text with a border around it to act as a button. I increased the text within this and since then half of the text jumps to the next line whenever the viewport is lower than 1200px.

I created a snippet to replicate this, but even that won't help, so this most likely has to be seen live. The area the issue is at is in the "Grow your business with us" section at the very bottom of that section (under the 3 images).

Please view it in a viewport of less than 1200px

What is causing the self made button to be on 2 lines? I have the width set to 100%?

```js
$(function() {
  $('#see-all-services-text').animate({
    opacity: 1,
    left: '0%'
  }, 700);
  })
```

```css
#home-img-block-section {
 width: 100%;
 height: 850px;
}
#see-all-services {
 width: 100%;
 height: 75px;
 text-align: center;
}
#see-all-services-text {
    opacity: 0;
 font-size: 1.3em;
 position: relative;
 left: -30%;
}
#see-all-services-text a {
 text-decoration: none;
 color: #45a5ba;
 cursor: pointer;
}
#see-all-services-button {
 padding: 15px 20px;
 border: 2px solid #45a5ba;
 transition: ease-in-out .5s;
}
#see-all-services-button:hover {
 border: 2px solid #45a5ba;
 color: #FFF;
 background: #45a5ba;
 transition: ease-in-out .5s;
}

/*---------------------------------------------- MEDIA QUERY 961 - 1200--------------------------*/

@media screen and (min-width: 961px) and (max-width: 1200px) {
#home-img-block-section {
 height: 670px;
}
#see-all-services-text {
 font-size: 1.2em;
}
}
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/1.11.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<div id="home-img-block-section">
  <div id="see-all-services">
    <div id="see-all-services-text"><a href="services"><span id="see-all-services-button">VIEW ALL WEB DESIGN SERVICES</span></a></div>
  </div>
</div>
```

Comment: do you want it to be aligned to center or right?

Comment: I just want it to be centered like it is on a larger viewport. It will like that in all viewports until I added more text to it.

Comment: Not related but I can't even get to that section. I am using OSX with a magic mouse and your scroll hijacking just launches me to the bottom of the site. Completely unusable.

Comment: On page load it does that or when you are in that section and hit the reload button?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

It's happening because your button is `inline` element. Set `display:inline-block;` to it and remove `width:100%;`, and everything should be ok.

Your snippet:

```js
$(function() {
  $('#see-all-services-text').animate({
    opacity: 1,
    left: '0%'
  }, 700);
  })
```

```css
#home-img-block-section {
 width: 100%;
 height: 850px;
}
#see-all-services {
 width: 100%;
 height: 75px;
 text-align: center;
}
#see-all-services-text {
    opacity: 0;
 font-size: 1.3em;
 position: relative;
 left: -30%;
}
#see-all-services-text a {
 text-decoration: none;
 color: #45a5ba;
 cursor: pointer;
}
#see-all-services-button {
 padding: 15px 20px;
    display: inline-block;
 border: 2px solid #45a5ba;
 transition: ease-in-out .5s;
}
#see-all-services-button:hover {
 border: 2px solid #45a5ba;
 color: #FFF;
 background: #45a5ba;
 transition: ease-in-out .5s;
}

/*---------------------------------------------- MEDIA QUERY 961 - 1200--------------------------*/

@media screen and (min-width: 961px) and (max-width: 1200px) {
#home-img-block-section {
 height: 670px;
}
#see-all-services-text {
 font-size: 1.2em;
}
}
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<div id="home-img-block-section">
  <div id="see-all-services">
    <div id="see-all-services-text"><a href="services"><span id="see-all-services-button">VIEW ALL WEB DESIGN SERVICES</span></a></div>
  </div>
</div>
```

Comment: This helped get it all on one line, but it positioned to the right side of the page instead of the center.

Comment: @Becky add `clear:both` to your `#see-all-services-text` element. You need to clear float context to have button below this block. Read about floats and how they works - https://css-tricks.com/all-about-floats/

Comment: That did it. Thanks!